# Error while indexing an array in google sheet

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Formula1 `ArrayFormula(regexextract(ArrayFormula(address(1,sequence(150,1,1,1),4)),"\D+"))`

Formula2 `if(and(5>=column(indirect(B2)),5<=columns(indirect(B2))+column(indirect(B2))-1),5,-1)`

B2 contains range E1:G4

Formula1 & 2 are working perfectly fine but when we combine both as mentioned below there is an error: "Function INDEX parameter 2 value is -1. Valid values are between 0 and 150 inclusive."

```
index(ArrayFormula(regexextract(ArrayFormula(address(1,sequence(150,1,1,1),4)),"\D+")),if(and(5>=column(indirect(B2)),5<=columns(indirect(B2))+column(indirect(B2))-1),5,-1))
```

I have deliberately used -1 which is not a valued value for index parameter 2 so that it gives error when "If" condition is unfulfilled and I can omit whole result with iferror function, but when condition is fulfilled then it shouldn't give any error. Any work around will not help me because I need to use this formula component in another complex formula.

[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17xd_uxkwrjTtKdFBdjB6wjQb3-R9S90SZaVDRScs0A8/edit#gid=0) with function

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(1, SEQUENCE(150, 1, 1, 1), 4), "\D+"),
 IF((5>=COLUMN(INDIRECT(B2)))*(5<=COLUMNS(INDIRECT(B2))+COLUMN(INDIRECT(B2))-1), 5, -1)))
```

Comment: That won't give me error when statement is false, I need error also.